# Twisted + Gtk - shutdown not working properly

Tags: python, pygtk, twisted, gtk

Using Python 2.6, Twisted 10.1, and GTK+ 2.22, with latest pygtk installed, I'm having problems on shutdown. When I close my application and shut down the reactor (using the `gtk2reactor` of course), the application simply freezes.

I've poked around the twisted source and added debug messages. What ends up happening is, the `'shutdown'` event fires, `PortableGtkReactor.crash` is called, which calls `gtk.main_quit`. The event gets processed at the end of `ReactorBase.runUntilCurrent`. When the function returns, control goes to `ReactorBase.iterate`, which returns control to `PortableGtkReactor.simulate`, which goes back to... the `gtk.main()` call. It looks like `gtk` just doesn't quit.

Unfortunately, when I put together a very simple example with twisted and the gtk "Hello World" sample, everything shut down correctly. It must be something my application is doing. Until I can figure it out further, though...

What might be causing this? Like what could an app do that causes gtk to not quit? The app worked fine on Gtk 2.12, with Python 2.5 and Twisted 8.1, if that helps at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326710/serious-instability-with-pygtk-2-22-and-python-2-6) it seems to come from importing the `win32ui` module. But I think the underlying problem is deeper..

EDIT: Seems to be a problem with my particular install of Windows 7 and whatever else is here.

Answer (score 0):

Threads, perhaps?  The Twisted reactor joins all threads on shutdown, and if you're doing something in a `callInThread` that hangs, your loop may be unable to stop.  (I'm not sure what the behavior would be if you're starting your own threads, either.)