# Serious instability with pygtk 2.22 and python 2.6

Tags: python, debugging, crash, gtk, pygtk

Has anybody come across this?

I've taken the GTK [HelloWorld sample](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/examples/helloworld.py). It runs fine. However, if i `import win32ui`, then it does not shutdown properly (as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308346/twisted-gtk-shutdown-not-working-properly) ).

There are other problems. In the process of narrowing down my application to see what caused it to not shutdown, I came upon a point where I was deconstructing a logger class I had written that I had no problems with. In the constructor I had the line:

```
self.logger = logger
```

I had commented out the rest of the class so `self.logger` was not even used. If I left the line as-is, I would get this error upon clicking the "Hello World" button:

```
c:\python26\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\gtk2reactor.py:350: GtkWarning: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
  gtk.main()
```

If I change the line to:

```
self.logger = 0
```

then the error would not show up. This happened with various other lines of code in the logger class as well. I suspect it would happen with other random bits of code, too. But in any case - setting a variable that **isn't even used** should **not** cause any kind of problem. Note that at this point I was still using twisted with pygtk. I haven't reproduced this yet with just gtk.

This makes me suspect pygtk is being really unstable... has anybody come across this before? Is there anything I can do? The reason I updated from `gtk 2.12` was because my application would crash randomly, but this is far worse.

UPDATE: The bugs happen on 64-bit Windows 7. I've tried both with 32-bit python with the versions listed above, and 64-bit python with pygtk-2.17.1, pygobject-2.21.2, pycairo-1.8.8 and pywin32-214.

So far the `win32ui` bug does not happen with the same install on a Windows XP VirtualBox virtual machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried this on a different install of Win7 64-bit on a different computer, and it worked fine. So it's some strange thing with the hardware/other software on a particular computer. Probably nothing gtk or win32 related.